# How to forward a public (network-accessible) port to a local (port or host)

Tags: ubuntu, port-forwarding, localhost, xampp

I'm using Ubutnu 9.04, and XAMPP as a testing server for my websites.
What I want to do is make my websites network-accessible. For now only the **my-ip-address:80** is accessible and managed by XAMPP.
But I want to add more ports like **my-ip-address:41100** for example and make it forwarding to a specific local host like (**my-custom-domain.local**) which I made by editing/configuring on **/etc/hosts** file and also **/opt/lampp/etc/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf**.

Thanks

Comment: Why do you want to change the ports?  apache's vhost combined with /etc/hosts should allow you to associate `my-custom-domain.local` with /docs/local and `my-custom-domain.remote` with /docs/remote.  I'm not getting the port angle.

Comment: Bcus the goal is to make my local-virtual-host-names available on my network.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I found a solution:

1. Make Apache listen to multiple ports like (44100, 44101, ..., 44199) because it's unused/unregistered ports. [you can edit httpd.conf of ports.conf to do this]
2. Allow incoming connections to these ports.
3. Add new virtual hosts and configure Apache to use these ports for those hosts (each host corresponds to one port).