# How to use local network machine as web host

Tags: port-forwarding

I use a wireless router to connect to a modem which connects the wall socket for DSL connection. I have several machines behind the router. The ISP provides me a static public IP. Now when I use the static public IP to visit, I always get to the modem's webpage rather than the router's webpage. Now I really want to use one machine as a website host. I try various ways including port forwarding on router, DMZ setting on router but the public IP still always points me to the modem rather than the router.

What I should do? Thank you very much.

Comment: It might be helpfull if you post the brand and model of your ROuter and modem, maybe one of us has the same

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to forward a public (network-accessible) port to a local (port or host)](http://superuser.com/questions/51629/how-to-forward-a-public-network-accessible-port-to-a-local-port-or-host)

Answer (score 0):

First, you will need to disable remote management on your router.

Next, you will need to install a webserver program which I will assume is already done.

Next, configure your webserver to work behind the router's Firewall this may entail disabling port 80 from the local firewall as well.

Finally, forward port 80 to the computer to host the website from within the router settings.

Note: The website will likely NOT work if you check it internally, depending on how your set up is.

Note2: Many ISPs block port 80.